# Conditional formatting based on another cell value

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'd like to format cell A338 so that, if that cell is blank and if cell H338 is not blank, then conditional formatting would apply.

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($H338)),(ISBLANK($A338)))
```

That didn't work. Where's my error?

Comment: I've aslo tried a different approach and didn't work: ==and(len(h338>0),len(a338)<0)

Comment: The issue might be data validation that I have in A338.                                 I've aslo tried a different approach and didn't work: ==and(len(h338>0),len(a338)<0)   Cell A338 has data validation, if I test these two formulas separately, the len(a338)<0) is the one that doesn't work on its own. My overall problem is that if I have an IF formula in cell A338 saying "Fill Out" if H338 is not blank, then I cannot click on the data validation arrow to select the answer for cell A338, so I thought I'd go the conditional formatting route.

Answer (score 1):

Select A338 and apply a **Custom formula is** of:

```
=and(A338="",H338<>"")
```

with formatting of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

[AND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301)

You were, presumably, not applying your formula to the correct range.